# Shell builtin read

Tags: bash, macos, solaris, ksh, aix

I am trying to mimic Linux `split -C 20mb <input-file>` implementation 
using ksh/bash builtin read. read/readarray/mapfile takes in number of bytes so the split output file(s) could end up with incomplete line(s) thus corrupted output.

How do I read from input-file close to 20mb bytes without line breaks?
(AIX, Solaris and MacOS split do not implement "-C" option hence the request)

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show sample inputs/outputs and your best attempt at coding a solution to your problem. Sorry, but requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: Read a line, write it to the output file, add the line length to a total variable. When the total is close to 20mb, start a new file and reset total to 0.

Comment: Or you could install `split` from GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is available via the bash's built-in help command:

```
$ help read
read: read ... [-n nchars] [-N nchars] ... [name ...]
...
  -n nchars return after reading NCHARS characters rather than waiting
            for a newline, but honor a delimiter if fewer than NCHARS
            characters are read before the delimiter
  -N nchars return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless
            EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any delimiter
```

`read -N $((20 * 1024 * 1024))` should let you read you 20Mb at a time, ignoring line breaks.